# PHP and MYSQL: Insert input select with mysql data and show all other fields when change selection

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html-select

I have this situation:

The table of my database is called reteconsolare and have these fields:

ID
Stato
Citta
Indirizzo
Telefono
Email
URL
Mappa
Descrizione (This is not really show. I use it only for showing the title of the images on Sito & Mappa links)

In this moment all works ok, just that When there are more "Citta" for "Stato" I wish that in the "Citta" colum would appear an input select with all the available name of the Citta for Stato ordering from A to Z and when changing the selection, should also show the correct Indirizzo, Telefono, Email, URL, Mappa.

Following is my actual code that repeat the values.

eg.:

Belgio  |  Bruxelles
Belgio  |  Charleroi

```
 <?Php
  mysqli_set_charset($connessione, 'utf-8');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM reteconsolare ORDER BY Stato, Citta";

    $query = $connessione->query($sql) ;
  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())  { 
        $stato=sprintf( $row["Stato"]); 
        $citta=sprintf( $row["Citta"]);
        $indirizzo=sprintf( $row["Indirizzo"]);
        $descrizione=sprintf( $row["Descrizione"]);
        $email=sprintf( $row["Email"]);
        $telefono=sprintf( $row["Telefono"]);
        $mappa=sprintf( $row["Mappa"]);
        $link=sprintf( $row["URL"]);
        $id=sprintf( $row["ID"]);
         ?>  


         <tr>
    <td width="20%"><ts><?Php echo($stato) ?></ts></td>
    <td width="20%"><ts><?Php echo($citta) ?></ts></td>
    <td width="30%"><ts><?Php echo($indirizzo) ?></ts></td>
    <td width="10%"><ts><?Php echo($telefono) ?></ts></td>
    <td width="10%"><ts><?Php echo emailize($email) ?></ts></td>

    <td width="5%" align="center"><?Php echo(' <a target=_blank href='); echo($link);  echo('>'); ?><img src="img/www.png" width="20" height="20" title="Link al sito del <?php echo ($descrizione);?>"></a></td>
    <td width="5%" align="center"><?Php echo(' <a target=_blank href='); echo($mappa);  echo('>'); ?><img src="img/Maps.png" width="20" height="20" title="Mappa del <?php echo ($descrizione);?>"></a></td>

      </tr>
   <?php } while ($row_news = $query->fetch_assoc());?>

<?php
    function emailize($text)
{
    $regex = '/(\S+@\S+\.\S+)/';
    $replace = '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>';

    return preg_replace($regex, $replace, $text);
}?>
```

I searched also an alternative way: not repeating the name of the Stato and Wrap every city with its data. I tried to play with mysql's group by... but without results. And anyway don't really like too much this solution. I think that i need  to know maybe also Ajax to solve this problem, but at the moment i can't learn it...Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check my answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing: store **"Stato"** in `array` and check if the value already exist in `array` or not. For i.e. :

```
<?Php
  mysqli_set_charset($connessione, 'utf-8');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM reteconsolare ORDER BY Stato, Citta";

    $query = $connessione->query($sql) ;
    $Stato = array() ;
  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())  { 
        if(!in_array(sprintf($row["Stato"]),$Stato)){
        $stato=sprintf( $row["Stato"]); 
        $Stato = sprintf( $row["Stato"]);
        $citta=sprintf( $row["Citta"]);
        $indirizzo=sprintf( $row["Indirizzo"]);
        $descrizione=sprintf( $row["Descrizione"]);
        $email=sprintf( $row["Email"]);
        $telefono=sprintf( $row["Telefono"]);
        $mappa=sprintf( $row["Mappa"]);
        $link=sprintf( $row["URL"]);
        $id=sprintf( $row["ID"]);
         ?>  


         <tr>
    <td width="20%"><ts><?Php echo($stato) ?></ts></td>
    <td width="20%"><ts><?Php echo($citta) ?></ts></td>
    <td width="30%"><ts><?Php echo($indirizzo) ?></ts></td>
    <td width="10%"><ts><?Php echo($telefono) ?></ts></td>
    <td width="10%"><ts><?Php echo emailize($email) ?></ts></td>

    <td width="5%" align="center"><?Php echo(' <a target=_blank href='); echo($link);  echo('>'); ?><img src="img/www.png" width="20" height="20" title="Link al sito del <?php echo ($descrizione);?>"></a></td>
    <td width="5%" align="center"><?Php echo(' <a target=_blank href='); echo($mappa);  echo('>'); ?><img src="img/Maps.png" width="20" height="20" title="Mappa del <?php echo ($descrizione);?>"></a></td>

      </tr>
   <?php }} while ($row_news = $query->fetch_assoc());?>

<?php
    function emailize($text)
{
    $regex = '/(\S+@\S+\.\S+)/';
    $replace = '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>';

    return preg_replace($regex, $replace, $text);
}?>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I copied Your modified code, But nothing changed... It still shows 2 times the same Stato in the column and the respective datas then are separeted.

Comment: @RobertoN can you paste both stato name here

Comment: Hi I have for example: Austria  with the only city Vienna, While I Have Belgium that at the moment have 2 Cities (Citta) That are Bruxelles and Carleroi. I would like that when there is more of 1 occurence of the same state (Stato) , the relatives cities are showed in an option select or showed wrapping down one to another with relatives datas, without repeasting the state name...

Comment: @RobertoN In this case PHP is not enough you have to use jQuery too.

Comment: I was thinking something like that... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check syntax in while:

```
 while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())  { 
...
} while ($row_news = $query->fetch_assoc());
```

Correct syntax:

```
while(condition) {
...
}
```

or

```
do {
...
} while(condition)
```